# Missing artifact error when adding a Maven dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am not familiar with maven but I need to add a [jnativehook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) dependency in a Java/Jersey project. I tried to add this dependency in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.1stleg</groupId>
  <artifactId>system-hook</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

But I get an error on Eclipse

> Missing artifact com.1stleg:system-hook:jar:2.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [this](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.1stleg), it should be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.1stleg</groupId>
    <artifactId>jnativehook</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

instead of

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.1stleg</groupId>
  <artifactId>system-hook</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope it helps!